# How to create associative entities with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables and a third associative entity table, such as this:

[image: ERD showing Books and Languages, both with one-to-many relationship to BookLanguages]

Books:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Book = sequelize.define(
    "Book",
    {
      title: DataTypes.STRING,
      author: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {}
  );
    
  Book.associate = function (models) {

    Book.belongsToMany(models.Language, {
      as: "BookLanguages",
      through: "BookLanguages",
      foreignKey: "bookId",
    });
  };
      
  return Book;
};
```

Languages:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Language = sequelize.define(
    "Language",
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {}
  );

  Language.associate = function (models) {

    Language.hasMany(models.Book, {
      as: "BookLanguages",
      through: "BookLanguages",
      foreignKey: "languageId",
    });
  };
  
  return Language;
};
```

Languages contains these records: 1. English, 2. French

I want to create a new book that is available in English and French.

Books Controller:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../../models/index");
const Book = db.Book;
const Language = db.Language;

exports.createBook = (req, res) => {
  Book.create({
   title: req.body.title,
   author: req.body.author,
   BookLanguages: req.body.languages // an array [1, 2]
 }, {
   include: [ { association: Language, as: "BookLanguages" } ]
  })
    .then((book) => {
      res.json({ status: 200, message: "Book created successfully!" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json({ status: 400, message: err });
    });
};
```

AFAICT from the Sequelize docs, this should be sufficient, but I am getting an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Can anyone see what I'm missing, or what I may have misunderstood about setting up these associations / associative entities?

Comment: Your `BookLanguages` table doesn’t need an id column. On a through table the primary key is actually a compound primary key made up of the two foreign key ids.

Comment: Do you have a circular import going on between book and languages? You might need to do your associations in a separate module.

Comment: @Glenn thanks, I'll look into that. Is the compound primary key mandatory, or will a separate id still work fine?

Comment: The Sequelize docs include this line: "An instance can be created with nested association in one step, provided all elements are new." I suspect the problem is that the languages elements are not being newly created - I'm trying to link elements that have already been created to a new one (Existing languages associated with a new book).

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this, the solution I went with was to rewrite my API with Laravel...probably not useful to many, but it's what I did!

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify primary key in the model for M:N to work.

{ type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true }

Association
M:N (belongsToMany) will always use primary foreign key is just alias for the PK, so it ok.However,since you alias one model then you have to tell sequelize what is the key that associate to another model using "otherKey".

```
Language.belongsToMany(models.Book, {
  as: "BookLanguages",
  through: "BookLanguages",
  foreignKey: "languageId",
  otherKey : "bookId"
});

Book.belongsToMany(models.Language, {
  as: "BookLanguages",
  through: "BookLanguages",
  foreignKey: "bookId",
  otherKey : "languageId"
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that seemed promising - but I still get the same Type Error. I noticed that if I change the alias in the include from the controller to something incorrect I still get the error, which makes me think I've got that alias wrong.